# unable to execute package control information extraction (dpkg-deb): Permission denied

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

I am facing error if I do any installation with sudo apt install for any package.
The error is irrespective of the package. And I am doing the installation with sudo su (root) user. Please advise. OS version:  Ubuntu 18.04

command:

```
sudo apt install consul
```

error details:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  consul
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 241 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/55.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 143 MB of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg (subprocess): unable to execute package control information extraction (dpkg-deb): Permission denied
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/consul_1.15.3-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/consul_1.15.3-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support